# Jquery .hasClass Issue

Tags: jquery

I need to run a script if a class has a specific classname.

Im using the supersized plugin and want to run this javascript if Slide-0 is the activeslide and if it is not the activeslide I dont want it to run the script.

The js code im using is below. Without the If statement it works fine but with the If statement it doesnt work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($("#supersized .slide-0").hasClass('activeslide'))
{$(function() {
            var $tf_bg              = $('#tf_bg'),
                $tf_bg_images       = $tf_bg.find('img'),
                $tf_bg_img          = $tf_bg_images.eq(0),
                $tf_thumbs          = $('#tf_thumbs'),
                total               = $tf_bg_images.length,
                current             = 0,
                $tf_content_wrapper = $('#tf_content_wrapper'),
                $down           = $('#down'),

                $tf_loading         = $('#tf_loading');

            //preload the images                
            $tf_bg_images.preload({
                onComplete  : function(){
                    $tf_loading.hide();
                    init();
                }
            });


            //shows the first image and initializes events
            function init(){
                //get dimentions for the image, based on the windows size
                var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
                //set the returned values and show the image
                $tf_bg_img.css({
                    width   : dim.width,
                    height  : dim.height,
                    left    : dim.left,
                    top     : dim.top
                }).fadeIn();

                //resizing the window resizes the $tf_bg_img
            $(window).bind('resize',function(){
                var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
                $tf_bg_img.css({
                    width   : dim.width,
                    height  : dim.height,
                    left    : dim.left,
                    top     : dim.top
                });
            });



                //click the arrow down, scrolls down
                $down.bind('click',function(){
                    if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                        return false;
                        scroll('tb');
                });



            }


            //show next / prev image
            function scroll(dir){
                //if dir is "tb" (top -> bottom) increment current, 
                //else if "bt" decrement it
                current = (dir == 'tb')?current + 1:current - 1;

                //we want a circular slideshow, 
                //so we need to check the limits of current
                if(current == total) current = 0;
                else if(current < 0) current = total - 1;


                //we get the next image
                var $tf_bg_img_next = $tf_bg_images.eq(current),
                    //its dimentions
                    dim             = getImageDim($tf_bg_img_next),
                    //the top should be one that makes the image out of the viewport
                    //the image should be positioned up or down depending on the direction
                        top = (dir == 'tb')?$(window).height() + 'px':-parseFloat(dim.height,10) + 'px';

                //set the returned values and show the next image   
                    $tf_bg_img_next.css({
                        width   : dim.width,
                        height  : dim.height,
                        left    : dim.left,
                        top     : top
                    }).show();

                //now slide it to the viewport
                    $tf_bg_img_next.stop().animate({
                        top     : dim.top
                    },1000);

                //we want the old image to slide in the same direction, out of the viewport
                    var slideTo = (dir == 'tb')?-$tf_bg_img.height() + 'px':$(window).height() + 'px';
                    $tf_bg_img.stop().animate({
                        top     : slideTo
                    },1000,function(){
                    //hide it
                        $(this).hide();
                    //the $tf_bg_img is now the shown image
                        $tf_bg_img  = $tf_bg_img_next;
                    //show the description for the new image
                        $tf_content_wrapper.children()
                                           .eq(current)
                                           .show();
            });
                //hide the current description  
                    $tf_content_wrapper.children(':visible')
                                       .hide()

            }

            //animate the image to fit in the viewport
            function resize($img){
                var w_w = $(window).width(),
                    w_h = $(window).height(),
                    i_w = $img.width(),
                    i_h = $img.height(),
                    r_i = i_h / i_w,
                    new_w,new_h;

                if(i_w > i_h){
                    new_w   = w_w;
                    new_h   = w_w * r_i;

                    if(new_h > w_h){
                        new_h   = w_h;
                        new_w   = w_h / r_i;
                    }
                }   
                else{
                    new_h   = w_w * r_i;
                    new_w   = w_w;
                }

                $img.animate({
                    width   : new_w + 'px',
                    height  : new_h + 'px',
                    top     : '0px',
                    left    : '0px'
                },350);
            }

            //get dimentions of the image, 
            //in order to make it full size and centered
            function getImageDim($img){
                var w_w = $(window).width(),
                    w_h = $(window).height(),
                    r_w = w_h / w_w,
                    i_w = $img.width(),
                    i_h = $img.height(),
                    r_i = i_h / i_w,
                    new_w,new_h,
                    new_left,new_top;

                if(r_w > r_i){
                    new_h   = w_h;
                    new_w   = w_h / r_i;
                }
                else{
                    new_h   = w_w * r_i;
                    new_w   = w_w;
                }


                return {
                    width   : new_w + 'px',
                    height  : new_h + 'px',
                    left    : (w_w - new_w) / 2 + 'px',
                    top     : (w_h - new_h) / 2 + 'px'
                };
                }

        });

}   
 </script>
```

Comment: Seeing your HTML structure would help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely at the time of the if statement, jQuery isn't ready yet.
Try putting it inside the ready function `$(function(){ if... })`

Comment: class slide-0 is a child of id supersized.

Here is a link to the site at the moment.
http://www.diegobecas.cl/art_directionvert.php

This code does not have the IF statement attached to it.

On the first slide you can go down to see other images.

I need to add the IF statement because I want to add this vertical not only to the first slide but to other slides and need to run a different code each time for each separate slideshow.

Comment: Ok got the first if tag working with putting

jQuery(window).load(function() {if...
Before everything.

Now I just have a quick other question. How can I rerun this js code on a click event. If i click #nextslide to go to the next slide I want it to run through this code again.

thanks!